# Is there a way to find out whether the registration of a device worked (Urban Airship)

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am having a checkbox for users to enable/disable push notifications.
The problem is that I can't tell the user that registration didn't work if something went wrong.
Is there a way to know whether there went something wrong with registering the device?